# Overlapped IO in wxWidgets application

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, wxwidgets, overlapped-io

I'm working on a *Windows-only* wxWidgets GUI application that shall receive asynchronous notifications from a service process via a named pipe. I would like to avoid spawning a separate thread for pipe handle monitoring. Hence, I'm thinking about using overlapped IO. My question is: what would be the most straight-forward way of receiving notifications for the pipe handle in the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to integrate an arbitrary `HANDLE` with wxWidgets event loop so the best solution is to use a separate thread and maybe call [wxQueueEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#gae921d7bd0e52fedbf3f253d2c408bce1) if you really need to modify the main thread.

Comment: I had to choose this route, after all. Apparently, there are no other options.